# Will let keyword work on ES5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

What will be the output of the following code in ES5 compiler? Will it throw any error or will it work fine?

```
let foo = 123;
let {x,y} = getValues();
```

Comment: Have you checked it?

Comment: While many implementations use jit (which still is not a static compile), javascript is in it's foundations an interpreted language, there is nothing like an "ES5 compiler".

Comment: @ASDF ECMAScript is just a language. A particular implementation of it may be compiled or interpreted.

Comment: @deceze True. I was mainly concerned, that OP assumed the default action for javascript was compilation, but did wrong wording of "doesn't exist" vs "is absolutely not the standard action". Wikipedia has a good wording with ["most of its implementations execute instructions directly and freely, without previously compiling"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

Comment: @ASDF Even that is… debatable. Any code needs to be *compiled* in some form or another. The CPU doesn't execute plain JS after all. The distinction is usually how much the compiler does and how much time it spends doing it. Something like C goes through a whole many steps of processing and optimisation, while "interpreted" usually mostly means that a lot of the optimisation and static analysis steps are skipped. However, modern JS engines will do quite expensive optimisation *sometimes* in parallel on the fly.

Comment: @deceze Compiling generally is a step done during the production of a program, while interpreting is generally done at runtime. The first is very untypical for javascript. I think further debating this is OT, and we both know a lot of the details, and will just debate about wording. Even wikipedia mentions on several occasions, that the terms are "not well defined" or "vague".

Answer (score 7):

Will not work. `let` was introduced in ES6.

Comment: Destructuring assignment was also introduced in ECMA 2015

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't work for an ES5 compiler. But using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) will solve this issue by transpiling your ES6 code down to compatible versions.